# Cascade Delete records in DB

Tags: php, sql, recursion

I have table with relations parent-childs:

```
id   text        parent_id
1   'test'       0
2   'test1'      1
3   'test2'      2
4   'test3'      0
```

I have a function that build tree like this:

```
test
  - test1
    -- test2
test3
```

For example, I want to delete test1, but I need to delete all his childs, how can I do this, or what technique I need to use?

I tried to add a foreign key on the same table, but it don't work

Comment: U can do this by some code logic or by multiple sql queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add constraint like this

```
ALTER TABLE 
    `table` 
ADD FOREIGN KEY 
    (`parent_id`) 
REFERENCES 
    `table` (`id`) 
ON UPDATE CASCADE 
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Important: your table must be **InnoDB**

Comment: When i try to alter my table, i have an error: (errno: 150)

Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed */ My query: ALTER TABLE `my_table`
 ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_relations` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `my_table` (`parent_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;

Comment: Truncate your table before, or show your table DDL if is impossible

Comment: rh_ipv6 | CREATE TABLE `rh_ipv6` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`address` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
`type` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
`node` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`ip_type` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
`mask` int(3) NOT NULL,
`product` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
`subnets` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`therange` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`group` int(5) DEFAULT '0',
`id_service` int(11) NOT NULL,
`status` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `start` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `end` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |

Comment: parent_id can not be 0, it should clearly match with id values

Comment: 0 mean that this record is root in tree, you can see it in my example

Comment: set parent_id as nullable column and default value NULL

Comment: CREATE TABLE `rh_ipv6` (  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  `address` varchar(64) NOT NULL,  ------  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),  KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`),  CONSTRAINT `rh_ipv6_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `rh_ipv6` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8